# part of jQuery functions executes only once. Slides js is called only once

Tags: jquery

The second part of jquery function executes only one time
The slides js part `$('#slides').slidesjs()` works once on first click and doesnt on the second, etc.
The alert part and htlm replacement  is ok though.
Any help would be much appreciated. thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".linkA").live("click", function(){
      $("#slides").html("");
      var jQueryfilterType = (jQuery(this).parent().parent().html());
      $("#slides").html(jQueryfilterType);
      $("#slides a").contents().unwrap();
      $("#slides li").contents().unwrap();

      alert("test");

      $('#slides').slidesjs({
         width: 940,
         height: 528,
         navigation: {
            effect: "fade"
         },
         pagination: {
            effect: "fade"
         },
         effect: {
            fade: {
               speed: 400
            }
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML too?  Is `#slides` nested inside `.linkA`?

Comment: Assume this refers to this plugin? http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: You realize when you do `.unwrap()` it *removes the parent element from the DOM*. I'm willing to bet your `#slides > a` has a parent `li` and you're removing that. Leaving a `ul` with `anchor elements`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first click, you are emptying the `#slides` element (by calling `html("")`) and re-populate it with new content.  Then you call `slidesjs()` on it.  So this works fine.  On your second click, you empty `#slides` again, add new content and try to call `slidejs()` again.  However, this time, `slidesjs` has already initialized that element once, so it won't do it again, even though the contents have changed.

To fix this, you probably want to `remove` the `#slides` element completely and add a new (non-initialized) element again.  This way, `slidesjs()` will work correctly on the new element/content.

Comment: You have just saved me so much time and any further headache to what I've already got with this problem. Thanks so much.